# What does "complete" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> Complete authentication using Face ID.

It's a UI, and does it mean "please complete authentication ..." or "Authentication using Face ID is completed"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here complete can be used in 2 ways, as an **adjective** and as a **verb**.
 When it is used as verb sentence gets converted to an imperative mood sentence and it orders one to complete one's authentication. When it is used as adjective it means - a complete authentication using face Id.